# Как сделать в HTML шестигранной прогрессбар с hoverable сторонами

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html5, svg

Я хотел бы отображать индикатор прогресса шестиугольника, как показано ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где каждая сторона представляет некоторые данные, - `data A`.
При наведении курсора на каждую сторону шестиугольника я хотел бы отобразить всплывающую подсказку, - `A is done'. Как мне этого добиться?

Я попробовал SVG и  [hexagonprogressbar.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Canvas-Based-Hexagon-Progress-Bar-Plugin-with-jQuery-Hexagon-Progress.html). 
и мог бы создать шестиугольник, но я не могу понять, как добавить эффект наведения на каждую сторону.

Вот как я создал шестиугольник, используя SVG `<path>`

```
path id="id67441526994471690" d="M150 0 L285 75 L285 225 L150 300 L15 225 L15 75 L150 0" stroke="rgb(49, 120, 115)" stroke-width="35" fill="transparent" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="2160" mask="url(#id67441526994471690)"></path>
```

Если я добавлю указатель `onhover`, это добавит событие всплытия со всех сторон. Но я хочу добавить отдельное событие для каждой  стороны шестиугольника.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50468708/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Я нарисовал шестиугольник, используя 6 линий, что позволило сделать стороны шестиугольника независимыми.

При наведении на каждую сторону шестигранника появляется всплывающая подсказка.

Подсказка (`tooltip`) обеспечивается командой svg `<title>`

```css
polyline:hover {
stroke:orange;
}
```

```html
<style>
polyline:hover {
stroke:orange;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 80 80"  >  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#233340" /> 
 
 <g  transform="translate(7 7) rotate(90 32 32)" stroke="#317873" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round">
 <title>A is done </title>
 <polyline id="p1" points="16 4.29, 48.5 4.29" />
 <polyline id="p2" points="48 4.29, 64 32" />
 <polyline id="p3" points="64 32, 48 59.71" />
 <polyline id="p4" points="48 59.71, 16 59.71" />
 <polyline id="p6" points="0 32, 16 4.29" /> 
 <polyline id="p5" points="16 59.71, 0 32" />
 
 </g>
 
 <text x="25" y="35" font-size="12" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> Linux</text>
 <text x="27" y="50" font-size="10" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> 100%</text>
 
  </svg>
```

Чтобы увидеть подсказку, удерживайте некоторое время курсор на любой стороне шестиугольника.

**Вариант с выводом индивидуальных подсказок для каждой секции**

```css
polyline:hover {
stroke:orange;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 80 80"  >  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#233340" /> 
 
 <g  transform="translate(7 7) rotate(90 32 32)" stroke="#317873" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round">
  <g>
  <title>Выполнен 1-ый этап </title>
 <polyline id="p1" points="16 4.29, 48.5 4.29" />
 </g> 
     <g>
      <title>Выполнен 2-ой этап </title>
    <polyline id="p2" points="48 4.29, 64 32" />
     </g> 
<g>
      <title>Выполнен 3-й этап </title>
    <polyline id="p3" points="64 32, 48 59.71" />
</g>    
     <g>
      <title>Выполнен 4-ый этап </title>
    <polyline id="p4" points="48 59.71, 16 59.71" />
     </g>  
  
 <g>
      <title>Выполнен 5-ый этап </title>
   <polyline id="p5" points="16 59.71, 0 32" />
</g>   

     <g>
      <title>Выполнен 6-ой этап </title>
   <polyline id="p6" points="0 32, 16 4.29" />
     </g> 
   
 
 </g>
 
 <text x="25" y="35" font-size="12" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> Linux</text>
 <text x="27" y="50" font-size="10" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> 100%</text>
 
  </svg>
```

Comment: За 100% Linux - 100% "+", не мог пройти мимо линукса :)

Comment: Поведение верхней правой границы, какое-то нелогичное по сравнению с остальными. Везде под низ уходит, а там нет

Comment: А можно у "выделенной" стороны повышать z-index? а то палится страшно(( И как быть, если нужны разные подсказки?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а что по `tooltip`ам?)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо)